# how to express at least one input required in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three input, and user is required to input at lease one of them, otherwise display error message.
how do I code in javascript about at least one?

Here is my code:

```
function validateProduct1()
{   
    let product1 = product1Input.value;
     validateInputNumber(product1,product1Error);
}
function validateProduct2()
{   
    let product2 = product2Input.value;
     validateInputNumber(product2,product2Error);
}
function validateProduct3()
{   let product3 = product3Input.value;
     validateInputNumber(product3,product3Error);
}


function validateInputNumber(product, message)
{

     if (product == "")
     {
         message.innerHTML = ``;
     }
     else if (isNaN(product) && product !="")
     {
        productError.innerHTML = `Required an Integer`;
     }
     else if (!isNaN(product))
     {
         if(!Number.isInteger(Number(product)))
         
         {
             message.innerHTML = `Required an Integer`;
         }
         else
         {
            message.innerHTML = ``;
         }
     }
}
```

I want to add lines:if (product1 == "" && product2 == "" && product3 =="")
productError.innerHTML = `At least buy one`;

Comment: Try this `(product1 === "" || product2 === "" || product3 ==="")`

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version of you JS code.

You do not need repeat the function again. I have added all into one function and calling that `onClick` you can change to match your scenario.

You can see i am validating one input always if its not filled the user will see message as `Atleast buy one` The other

Run the snipped below to see it in action.

```js
function validateProduct() {

  let product1 = document.getElementById("demo1").value;
  let product2 = document.getElementById("demo2").value;
  let product3 = document.getElementById("demo3").value;

  if (product1 != '') {
     validateInputNumber(product1);
  } else {
    validateInputNumber(product1);
    validateInputNumber(product2);
    validateInputNumber(product3);
  }

}

function validateInputNumber(product) {

  let msg = document.getElementById("error");

  if (product == "") {
    msg.innerHTML = `Aleast buy one. Thanks`;
  } else if (isNaN(product) && product != "") {
    msg.innerHTML = `Required an Integer`;
  } else if (!isNaN(product)) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(Number(product))) {
      msg.innerHTML = `Required an Integer`;
    } else {
      msg.innerHTML = `All is good`;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="demo1" />

<input id="demo2" />

<input id="demo3" />

<button onclick="validateProduct()">Validate</button>

<div id="error"></div>
```

Comment: yes, it is exactly what I need to accomplish, thanks

Comment: @DongY glad to hear that. Don’t  forget to upvote or accept as “the” answer. Thanks